# How to load MNIST data sequentially for training?

Tags: python, tensorflow, mnist

I am now using MNIST and a colored-digits version for training my SemGAN model. I already load and preprocess the dataset.

```
x_train = x_train[0:10000]
y_train = y_train[0:10000]
x_test = x_test[0:10]
y_test = y_test[0:10]
x_train = x_train.reshape(-1, 28, 28, 1).astype(np.float32)
x_test = x_test.reshape(-1, 28, 28, 1).astype(np.float32)
```

Now I have to feed this every reshaped data (28, 28, 1) sequentially to the model(in batches or shuffle batch), how can I do it? Can anyone help me?

Comment: What framework are you using: tensorflow, pytorch? There's generally a lot of tutorials out there that you should be able to use for reference, especially for something as relatively straightfoward as feeding in datasets.

Comment: Thank you for replying, Andrew. I'm using TensorFlow 1.15. What I want to get is that input_i represents the tensor from MNIST, and then I do  `inputs_i=tf.train.batch(input_i, Batch_size)`. The question is how I can get this input_i.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to define a neural network architecture. Here's a simple CNN just for illustration purposes, you can research the GAN architecture for your case and build it up or make a separate question.

```
mnist_model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16,[3,3], activation='relu',
                            input_shape=(None, None, 1)),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16,[3,3], activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10)
])
```

Then you'll need to compile your losses, optimizers, metrics, etc. Again, here's a basic compile for classification.

```
mnist_model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
                    metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy()])
```

Now, on to your question. Once everything is set up, you can just use the model's fit function like this

```
mnist_model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=64, epochs=1, shuffle=True, validation_split=0.05)
```

There's a batch size of 64, so the fit goes through all the batches at intervals of 64 until they are completed. There's a split parameter for validation, to check the model is training (and not overtraining) -- as such, combined with the 64 batch size, there will be ceil(60000*0.95/64) iterations where the 60000 comes from the size of the training set (you've selected 10000). The call, in this case and by default, will randomly shuffle the training set per epoch. Lastly, there's an epoch of 1, but in reality you'd probably want this much higher.

Comment: Thanks, I get your point. But for my model, I didn't use model.fit() for training. And my inputs are mnist image, corresponding one-hot encoding label, colored-version mnist image, correponding one-hot encoding label. So four inputs are going to be fed into the model with proper batch size. The original label y_train is not used in here. That's why this question bothers me  a lot.

Comment: @QINGXIA all that should largely be handled by your input layer, architecture, and loss function. You'd have to post more specific code and your specific problem you've encountered for more help.

Comment: Thanks, Andrew, I will try to figure it out with your provided information.